# How do you do branching endings in a comic book?

Tags: creative-writing, comics

There are sometimes 2 or more endings in video games.  In video games, it's simple because the ending is determined by the character choices, but in a comic book, it's not too obvious so how would you do it. The issue is that if you choose to show both possible endings, it would be confusing for the readers, and so I am wondering if there's a way to make it clear it's one of two possible endings to the story. How can you do that? Any example of it?

The issue is how to show various endings and tell the viewers when the next ending starts and ends without explicitly telling the readers by showing a text saying "Ending Number 2".

Comment: How you could do a branching story is similar to [this question](/questions/62849). What works there would work for a comic as well. But if you only want to suggest that a different ending of the story is _possible_. Well. Isn't that _obvious_? Your characters should be making choices that _matter_. If choices matter, making a different choices leads to a different ending.

Comment: I've watched a theatre play where one of the characters has to make a choice in the first scene. Then, the play alternately shows scenes from both "branches" corresponding to the two choices that the character could have made. Effectively the play was showing us two stories in parallel. It worked great. I don't think it would have worked that well if only the ending was branching, as opposed to the whole story.